# Editable table (remove text and add text field on click) fires too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this table that I want to make editable. In order to do so, I have a simple event listener that removes the text from the `td` element and appends a input field with that text as the value. The value of that text field is then appended to the `td` once the text field loses focus.

**The problem** is it fires when the user, for example, tries to highlight and delete the text (click).

I changed the selector to exclude the specific input field's class, but to no avail.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.text_field:not(.remove_text)').click(function() {

        var text   = $(this).text().trim(),
            length = text.length;

         $(this).empty()
                .append("<input type='text' class='remove_text' size='"+length+"' value='"+text+"' />")
                .find('.remove_text')
                .focusout(function() {
                    $(this).closest('td').empty().append($(this).val());
                })
                .focus();  

    });
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uxf6yy7/)** to show what I mean.

Is there something wrong with the selector or something?

Comment: sounds like `dblclick` would be better for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be to add some logic to prevent emptying the table cell if it already contains an input element.

```
$('.text_field:not(.remove_text)').click(function() {
    if( $(this).find('input').length > 0 ) {                        
        return;
    }
    // your existing code
}
```

Here is a working example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uxf6yy7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The selector is only used once for attaching the event listener. If you want to check the condition every time, it might be better to put it inside the handler:

```
$('.text_field').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".remove_text") || $(e.target).closest(".remove_text").length > 0) return;

    //Otherwise, execute code
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/5uxf6yy7/3/